# How is it possible to add two arrays without using a loop?

Tags: cuda

The following program ([found here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/even-easier-introduction-cuda/)) uses a loop to add two arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

// Kernel function to add the elements of two arrays
__global__ void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
    y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

int main(void)
{
  int N = 1<<20;
  float *x, *y;

  // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
  cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float));

  // initialize x and y arrays on the host
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
  {
    x[i] = 1.0f;
    y[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
  int blockSize = 256;
  int numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
  add<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(N, x, y);

  // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
  float maxError = 0.0f;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i]-3.0f));
  std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

  // Free memory
  cudaFree(x);
  cudaFree(y);
  
  return 0;
}
```

.

On the other hand, the following program doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 512

__global__ void add(int n, float *x, float *y) 
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < n) {
        y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
    }
}

int main() 
{
    // Allocate memory on the GPU for the arrays
    float *a, *b;
    cudaMalloc(&a, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&b, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float));

    // Initialize the arrays on the host (CPU)
    float host_a[ARRAY_SIZE], host_b[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        host_a[i] = i;
        host_b[i] = i * 2;
    }

    // Copy the arrays from the host (CPU) to the device (GPU)
    cudaMemcpy(a, host_a, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(b, host_b, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Launch a kernel to add the arrays
    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid = (ARRAY_SIZE + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    add<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(ARRAY_SIZE, a, b);

    // Copy the result from the device (GPU) to the host (CPU)
    float host_result[ARRAY_SIZE];
    cudaMemcpy(host_result, b, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Print the result
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        std::cout << host_a[i] << " + " << host_b[i] << " = " << host_result[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // Free the memory on the GPU
    cudaFree(a);
    cudaFree(b);

    return 0;
}
```

However, they accomplish the same outcomes.

Please explain why and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA intends to get work done in parallel by spinning up many threads.  The definition of "what each thread will do" is given by the kernel code.

The kernel code that doesn't have a loop intends that each thread will update one output point, and therefore to cover all output points, you will need to spin up (at least) as many threads as there are output points.

The kernel code that has a loop may have a single thread perform the work for multiple output points.  Therefore it can get the same "work" done using fewer threads.

The [grid stride loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) discusses a canonical relationship between these two methods of grid-sizing.  The CUDA grid is the total or collection of all threads that are spun up for a particular kernel launch.

The example you have shown with a loop is indeed using a grid-stride loop, and that particular design can perform a fixed work definition with a more-or-less arbitrary number of threads.

For an orderly introduction to CUDA you may be interested in [this](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/) training course.